# How to apply generic type for inner function in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a generic function in typescript which basically do a filter from the array. Here is the equivalent function in javascript

```
const filterByProp = function (prop, value) {
    return function (item) {
        return item[prop] === value;
    }
}

const result = people.filter(filterByProp('age', 3))
```

The above code is working fine,the same thing want to convert into typescript.

Below typescript function is working fine. but the inner function doesn't have any type :(

Version 2:

```
const filterByProp2 = function <T, K extends keyof T>(prop: K, value: T[K]) {
    return function (item): boolean {
        return item[prop] === value;
    }
}
```

Version 3:

Below **code is not working as expected**. After applied type for an inner function.

```
const filterByProp3 = function <T, K extends keyof T>(prop: K, value: T[K]) {
    return function <T>(item: T): boolean {
        return item[prop] === value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
const result3 = people.filter(filterByProp3<IUser, 'age'>('age', 3)) // Not sure how to pass for inner func <IUser>
```

I got an error like

```
[ts] Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'T'.
[ts] This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'T[K]' and 'T[K]' have no overlap.
```

Can some please help how to solve this?

Version 4: This is working but I prefer to solve the version 3 problem.

```
function filterByProp4<T, K extends keyof T>(
    prop: K,
    entities: T[],
    value: T[K]
) {
    return entities.filter(e => e[prop] === value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify the same type parameter on the inner function. Typescript will infer `T` based on the expected return type of the outer function when you use it as an argument to filter so no explicit type parameters are needed:

```
interface Person { 
    age: number
}
const filterByProp = function <T, K extends keyof T>(prop: K, value: T[K]) {
    return function (item: T): boolean {
        return item[prop] === value;
    }
}
const people: Person[] = [{ age: 3}, { age: 2}];
const result = people.filter(filterByProp('age', 3))
people.filter(filterByProp('age', "3")) //error
people.filter(filterByProp('Age', 3)) //error
```